# Image returns to its original scale value when moving

Tags: javascript, css

I have an image that scales depending on your screen size, as the screen get smaller I scale the image even more. The problem is when I add a parallax effect and do a transformY(). For some reason when I move the image using transformY(), the image returns to its original scale value of 1.

```
@media (max-width: 1560px) {
   img {
     transform: scale(2);
   }
}

onScroll() {
   image.style.transform = `translateY(${window.pageYoffset * 0.7})`;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the cascading nature of CSS, if you re-apply the transform declaration, only the latest changes will be applied. Hence you have to trnasform again after translate to apply the latest changes. 
Please apply the media resolution on scroll again or call the method if you're using SCSS.

Answer (score 1):

In `onScroll` function, you override transform css crule.
It could be more convenient to wrap the image into a element and apply scale to it. e.g:

```
<div clas="img-container">
   <img ... />
</div>

@media (max-width: 1560px) {
   .img-container {
     transform: scale(2);
   }
}

onScroll() {
   image.style.transform = `translateY(${window.pageYoffset * 0.7})`;
}
```

Comment: image.style.transform = `translateY(${
      window.pageYOffset * 0.5
    }px) scale(1.8)`; that's what I did and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can make life easier by setting a CSS [custom variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) and adjusting *only* its value.

```js
const img = document.querySelector('img');

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

function onScroll() {
  let offsetY = (window.pageYOffset * 0.7) + 'px';
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--tY', offsetY);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --tY: 0px;
}

img {
  will-change: transform;
  transform: scale(2) translateY(var(--tY));
}

body {
  height: 4000px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="">
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antibland/krqwctjg/32/)